# Rendering opengl on external display using Monotouch

Tags: opengl-es, xamarin.ios

I would like to render my opengl 2.0 based iPad game on an external display, if available, in a higher resolution than the internal display.

Today I use the standard opengl template that comes with Monotouch for setting up the game loop and it's rendering via the iPhoneOSGameView. But I cannot find any examples or clues on how to set up the rendering on an external display.

Answer (score 3):

It turned out to be the iPhoneOSGameView that was in the way, it seems it's basically not designed for flexible rendering. Instead I turned to GLKit and tossed iPhoneOSGameView out the window, making it quite easy to change the rendering target in OpenGl from one window to another. Works great, the only drawback is it wont work on non iOS 5 devices, but that is not a big issue anyway.